# Passing GET variables to shell_exec in PHP

Tags: php, shell, get, mamp

I'm trying to run a shell script in PHP on my server that use `youtube-dl` to download a video. My code look like this:

```
<form action="download.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="link"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and my `download.php` look like this:

```
<?php
$link = escapeshellarg($GET["link"]);
$output = shell_exec('/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin/youtube-dl ' .$link. ' 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

So when I insert a link in my form, it should pass the link to the shell_exec and run the command with this link, but what I got is this:

```
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL.
```

Which means that command didn't received the link from GET. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET-parameters are accessed via $_GET-variable. Notice the underscore before the "GET".

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: This seems to work, but I got a different error now, `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
shell_exec("/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin/youtube-dl {$link} 2>&1");
```

Comment: What you are getting in $link variable?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$link = escapeshellarg($GET["link"]);
```

to

```
$link = escapeshellarg(urldecode($_GET["link"]));
```

and make sure you are getting url in `$_GET["link"]`